# PHP/Swift JSON Serialization on array of list of items results in zero elements

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, uitableview

Hi I'm new here and very new to programming but will try to make this issue as clear as possible. Essentially I have a table created from a SQL query that gives a list of items/objects in a user's inventory based on their userID. The table looks something like this (where userID is 5) - apologize as I do not have enough rep to post pictures yet:
[user 5's inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjOvZ.png)

I was going to have a tableView in Swift populate that table but when I ran into issues with converting the response I instead just made a separate ViewController with a button to run the checkInventory function, so I can print out all the data and see where the issue is.

First here is my PHP function to check the inventory:

```
public function getUserInventory($userID) {

$returnValue = array();

$sql = "select aObjects.objectID, objectDescription from aUsers join aInventory on aUsers.userID = aInventory.userID join aObjects on aInventory.objectID = aObjects.objectID where aUsers.userID='" .$userID. "'" ;

try {

$statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();

$statement->bind_result($objectID, $objectDescription);

}

catch (PDOException $e) 

{

print $e->getMessage();

}

$result = $statement->get_result();

if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) 

{


$row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (!empty($row)) {

$returnValue = $row;

}

}

return $returnValue;

}
```

The PDO Exception line might be unnecessary/incorrect because I'm using mysqli but regardless here is the other PHP file that calls that function:

```
<?php 

set_include_path('.:/testservice/');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$userID = $data["userID"];
//$userID = htmlentities($_GET["userID"]); <--- for testing

include 'Conn.php';  /* connection file */
include 'aSQLDao.php'; /* rest of php file */

$dao = new aSQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userInventory = $dao->getUserInventory($userID);

echo json_encode($userInventory);
return;

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

I am 90% sure the root of my issue lies in my PHP not giving out a JSON output that Swift can read properly. When  I use postman to check the PHP with userID = 5, I get an object that looks nice but seems to have an underlying problem with its format:

```
[
{
    "objectID": 1,
    "objectDescription": "alien"
},
{
    "objectID": 2,
    "objectDescription": "forestMonster"
},
{
    "objectID": 10,
    "objectDescription": "tank"
},
{
    "objectID": 9,
    "objectDescription": "fish"
}
]
```

In swift I have just been setting the variable userID to 5 to test it out and going through the general request + serialization process:

```
@IBAction func inventoryButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let userID = "5"
        let myURL = URL(string: "http://myIP/testservice/inventoryCheck.php");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myURL!);
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        let getString = ["userID": userID] as [String: String]
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: getString, options: .prettyPrinted)
                   } catch let error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        displayMessage(userMessage: "Something went wrong")
                       return
                }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                       data, response, error in

                        if error != nil {
                           self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not perform")
                            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                            return
                        }

                        do {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                            print(json)
```

There's more but based on breakpoints I am unable to convert this data correctly at the JSONSerialization step. When using "as! NS Dictionary" I get the **"Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10ad29a88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10ad2b1a8)."** error.

When using "as! NSArray" I get an **empty set of parantheses**. I tried also using Array> which resulted in an empty set of brackets. I have tried setting userID to int as well but from what I've read that should not affect this.

I apologize if there is any details missing here. Since it seems to be a pretty simple case of transferring a SQL table to UITableView I assume there is either a major piece I am missing or I am doing the wrong set of operations.

UPDATE: I did figure out that the Server is just not receiving my userID key correctly which is strange but at least hopefully rules out that PHP or Swift is incorrect - assume both answers provided would work if the variable was sent correctly to the script

SOLVED: For whatever reason this issue was solved when changing the HTTPRequest from GET to POST - seemed to be an issue with the PHP input not working for a GET request. I'll update this post with more specific details for future reference when I figure out how to make the GET request work properly as this should be GET and not POST. Both answers provided are right in terms of changing NSDictionary to NSArray or [[String:Any]]

Comment: What happens when you try to unwrap it as [[String: Any]] ?

Comment: If I switch that in for NSDictionary it returns empty brackets. Were you referring to that or the getString?

Comment: The data you showed for userID = 5 is an array of dictionaries, so you should use `[[String: Any]]` which is an array of dictionaries in Swift- you should not be trying to use NSDictionary(or NSArray really).  But, the bigger issue seems to be that on the swift side the serialization is successful (since you are returning empty brackets, and therefor an empty but existing array, instead of nil), so there is most likely a data formatting issue in your PHP code.

Comment: The raw data output for the PHP is "[{"objectID":1,"objectDescription":"alien"},{"objectID":2,"objectDescription":"forestMonster"},{"objectID":10,"objectDescription":"tank"},{"objectID":9,"objectDescription":"fish"}] and I posted the JSON above for reference. So an array with four objects - each object a dictionary with two key-value pairs. I agree the issue is somewhere in the PHP but not sure where and been hitting my head against this wall for about three days looking everywhere to try to get what is the error.

Comment: I believe the values for each of the array objects [0],[1], etc make it unparseable for JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deserialization line is here:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

You are trying to force-cast to NSDictionary.  The problem is your data structure is an Array.

```
[ // this will convert to an array
    { // this will convert to a dictionary
        "objectID": 1,
        "objectDescription": "alien"
    },
    ...
]
```

You have a couple of choices.  You can change her JSON to produce a Dictionary, or you can change your deserializer to expect an Array.

Here's the second case in code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var dataStr = """
[ { "objectID": 1, "objectDescription": "alien" }, { "objectID": 2, "objectDescription": "forestMonster" }, { "objectID": 10, "objectDescription": "tank" }, { "objectID": 9, "objectDescription": "fish" }]
"""
var data = dataStr.data(using: .utf8)

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

And the result:

[image: xcode result]

Comment: This definitely would seem to be the right answer. When I attempted that at one point I got an empty set of parentheses but when I try it now with "as? NSArray" I get "Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x60400045ab50>(

)
)" as the value for json. I'll attempt different ways to unwrap it but seems the array itself has some issues. I'll update this soon. Any chance I have to further deserialize the objects within the array?

Comment: This is correct but my underlying issue was that it needed to be a POST and not a GET request as updated above

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should first get your JSON-parsing code in order before you start to deal with your `dataTask` and such. Throwing in some `Codable` to become more Swifty you get something like

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
[
{
    "objectID": 1,
    "objectDescription": "alien"
},
{
    "objectID": 2,
    "objectDescription": "forestMonster"
},
{
    "objectID": 10,
    "objectDescription": "tank"
},
{
    "objectID": 9,
    "objectDescription": "fish"
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct MyObject: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let description: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "objectID"
        case description = "objectDescription"
    }
}



do {
    let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyObject].self, from:jsonData)
    print(obj)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will give you much more handy Swift objects with minimal effort and `JSONDecoder` would usually tell you if something is wrong with the JSON delivered (which there is not in this case).

With this in place you should print your raw data (by converting it into a `String` before doing so) in order to know what you throw at your parser (`JSONDecoder`).